# How do I write to a pin on a Microcontroller?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic

In our school project, we have to write a code for a "soft start" to our miniature elevator. I'm supposing what they mean is that we should use the POWER-UP-timer so that the voltage levels stabilize after a restart. So in the block diagram, it seemed to be connected to VDD and VSS, which is ports 5 and 14. How do I write the code? Is there something I'm forgetting?

I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Every microcontroller is different and the answer depends on checking the documentation for it.

Comment: Does "soft start" refer to the microcontroller power-up? Or does it simply mean that the elevator acceleration increases slowly?

Comment: The teacher doesn't have a lot of information for us, so my guess was that it is with the power-up since I don't have any information at all how to even address the acceleration.

Comment: And also since we're also working with how to connect the PIC to different voltage and getting the right amount of voltage over the VDD and VSS. So that's why I also think it's about power-up

Answer (score 3):

Soft start is where the motor starts slowly and gradually increases speed.

This is very useful especially in high-speed elevators as it keeps the passengers alive and happy.

If it's a brush motor use PWM. If it's a stepper vary the step rate and maybe use microstepping. if it's an induction motor your task is to build a VFD, good luck!

Comment: thank you! Any idea to code the escelation of the PWM?

Comment: ty for the second sentence - ymmd  

Comment: PWM is just turning on and off rapidly, most microcontrollers have some I/Os than can be programmed to produce PWM, or you can just use a timing loop.